# Title tip in react-select ellipsing

Tags: javascript, react-select

I'm using react-select with large text. I am ellipsing the data in the dropdown but want to show the entire text in the title tip.

here is the code:

```
<Select
    name='typeahead'
    options={options}
    placeholder={this.props.placeholder || labels.select}
    searchable={this.props.searchable || true}
    value={value}
    title={value}
    multi={multiple}
    matchProp='label'
    valueKey='value'
    clearable={multiple}
    disabled={disabled}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    onFocus={this.onFocus}
    clearValueText={labels.clearValueText}
    clearAllText={labels.clearAllText}
    noResultsText={labels.noResultsFound}
/>
```

I would like the entire text to be displayed in the tool-tip but it seems to be trimming it to something like 500 characters (in IE Edge) and 1024 in Chrome or Opera. I know this tool-tip limitation is in the browser so would it be possible to display my own custom tool-tip?

Comment: Are you saying the selectable options are large text (only partially showing) and should display a tool-tip of the entire text when hovered over?

Comment: Correct. I need the entire text to show but the browser limitations on title are stopping me. I'm going to try this:                                                             
      title={<my function to create custom title tip>}